# Printing Canvas using PrintDialog in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I am trying to take the print of Canvas in A4 size by setting height and width to  29.7cm and 21cm respectively.

I am getting proper output on Windows 7 devices. But for Windows 10 devices, the print output is not same as Windows 7 devices.

The real problem is height and width is not maintained for Windows 10 devices.

Please Help and Suggest Me !!

**Please find below code:**

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSolution.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Height="29.7cm"
        Width="21cm"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid x:Name="grdTest" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           Height="29.7cm"
                Width="21cm">
         <Canvas x:Name="cnvTest"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Height="29.7cm"
                Width="21cm"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        </Canvas>               
    </Grid>         
</window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog prnt = new PrintDialog();

            if (prnt.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                prnt.PrintVisual(cnvTest, "Printing Canvas");
            }
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution. courtesy **Magnus (MM8)**

Please find solution on the below link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b26c7898-169a-4726-b582-e79dc63f8450/printing-canvas-using-printdialog-in-wpf?forum=wpf

Here is a copy of the answer from the site, assuming a canvas with the name cnvTest:

```cs
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog prnt = new PrintDialog();
        if (prnt.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
        Size pageSize = new Size(prnt.PrintableAreaWidth, prnt.PrintableAreaHeight);
        cnvTest.Measure(pageSize);
        cnvTest.Arrange(new Rect(5, 5, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));

        if (prnt.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            prnt.PrintVisual(canvas, "Printing Canvas");
        }
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printer = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
        System.Printing.LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new System.Printing.LocalPrintServer();

        System.Printing.PrintTicket pt = new System.Printing.PrintTicket();
        System.Printing.PrintQueue pq = new System.Printing.PrintQueue(localPrintServer, printer.PrinterName, System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter);

        System.Printing.PageMediaSize PMS = new System.Printing.PageMediaSize(canvas.ActualWidth + 20, canvas.ActualHeight + 20);
        System.Windows.Size pageSize = new System.Windows.Size(canvas.ActualWidth+20, canvas.ActualHeight+20);
        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
        canvas.Measure(pageSize);




        pt.PageMediaSize = PMS;
        pt.PageMediaType = System.Printing.PageMediaType.Unknown;


        pq.DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize = PMS;
        pq.DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaType = System.Printing.PageMediaType.Unknown;



        printDialog.PrintQueue = pq;
        printDialog.PrintTicket = pt;
        printDialog.PrintQueue.Commit();


        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            printDialog.PrintVisual(canvas, "Test");
        }
```